# Replacing states with country name pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Is there a way to change state abbreviations into "USA" in a data frame :

```
'CIBA GEIGY CORP,BASIC PHARMACEUT RES,ARDSLEY,NY 10502'
```

to

```
'CIBA GEIGY CORP,BASIC PHARMACEUT RES,ARDSLEY,USA 10502'
```

I tried with a dictionary: `df.Authors.str.translate(us_states)` and also `.apply(lambda x: x.translate(us_states))` but it isn't working.
Do you have any ideas?

Dictionary with the changes that I need to make:

```
us_states= {'AL': 'USA',
 'AK': 'USA',
 'AZ': 'USA',
 'AR': 'USA',
 'CA': 'USA',
 'CO': 'USA',
 'CT': 'USA',
 'DE': 'USA',
 'DC': 'USA',
 'FL': 'USA',
 'GA': 'USA',
 'HI': 'USA',
 'ID': 'USA',
 'IL': 'USA',
 'IN': 'USA',
 'IA': 'USA',
 'KS': 'USA',
 'KY': 'USA',
 'LA': 'USA',
 'ME': 'USA',
 'MD': 'USA',
 'MA': 'USA',
 'MI': 'USA',
 'MN': 'USA',
 'MS': 'USA',
 'MO': 'USA',
 'MT': 'USA',
 'NE': 'USA',
 'NV': 'USA',
 'NH': 'USA',
 'NJ': 'USA',
 'NM': 'USA',
 'NY': 'USA',
 'NC': 'USA',
 'ND': 'USA',
 'MP': 'USA',
 'OH': 'USA',
 'OK': 'USA',
 'OR': 'USA',
 'PW': 'USA',
 'PA': 'USA',
 'PR': 'USA',
 'RI': 'USA',
 'SC': 'USA',
 'SD': 'USA',
 'TN': 'USA',
 'TX': 'USA',
 'UT': 'USA',
 'VT': 'USA',
 'VI': 'USA',
 'VA': 'USA',
 'WA': 'USA',
 'WV': 'USA',
 'WI': 'USA',
 'WY': 'USA'}
```

So each abbreviation should turn into "USA"

Comment: can you show us what is `us_states`?

Comment: @anky_91 done, please see the edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
pattern = '|'.join(','+state+' ' for state in us_states)
df.Authors.str.replace(pattern, ',USA ')
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use `df.replace` (works for `pd.Series` too):

`df['Authors'].replace(us_states, inplace=True, regex=True)`.

Documentation here:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html

Comment: I tried it but its not working, also the link that you sent is not working

Comment: Yep - you need to use `regex=True`. I've updated the answer and the link. But you'll need to update the lookup dictionary to be regex-style otherwise other substrings will be replaced!